# Couldn't load images on html on plugin processing (Linux and Windows)

Tags: qgis-plugins, image, html, template, path

## Context

I develop a processing plugin for QGSI 2.18 and in design GUI with *.ui files (Qt4)

I can’t load PNG **images** with **relative path** in **html** defined in **.ui files**

## Works with absolute path

It works with absolute path like this, but this is NOT portable :

```
<img src="/home/me/.qgis/python/plugin/Chloe/image/chloe2.png?width=668&amp;height=250" height="250" width="668" alt="chloe2.png"/></p>
```

## I search to solve these constraints

- use relative path to the plugin directory (Example for me : /home/me/.qgis/python/plugin/Chloe)
- work on Linux and Windows.